# How to get StackPane's child using the child's variable name

Tags: java, javafx

```
TabPane tabpaneSubs = new TabPane();
stackPane.getChildren().add(tabpaneSubs);

button.setOnAction( actionEvent -> {
     stackPane.getChildren().get(1).toFront();
}
```

Instead of using `.get(1)` i want to use the variable's name : `tabpaneSubs`

How do i do that ?

Comment: don't get the problem: you know the field name is `tabpaneSubs`, then what's wrong with just using it?

Comment: Right ! thank you.
i'm overthinking this way too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work simply because you already know your `TabPane` is a child at compile time:

```java
button.setOnAction( actionEvent -> {
     tabpaneSubs.toFront();
});
```

More generally, you should use the `id` property to find specific things

```java
tabpaneSubs.setId("my-tab-pane");

button.setOnAction( actionEvent -> {
     for(Node node : stackPane.getChildren()) {
       if("my-tab-name".equals(node.getId()){
         node.toFront();
         return;
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but can u elaborate on why using id instead of the variable name?

Comment: No idea, perhaps your actual solution has more to it than this example (which can be handled by case #1). @kleopatra, presumably you mean 'n' which I will update :)